# Sumar Monto de filas duplicadas usando group by e inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, datatables

tengo una sentencia en SQL en la que en una tabla tengo varios registros con el mismo número secuencial pero diferente monto y diferente fecha de creación ya que varia por segundos, hago inner join con otras tablas para traer más información que se requiere, solo que no encuentro como sumar el monto de los registros con el mimos secuencial y al mismo tiempo agruparlos agruparlos, mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT conCuentasConcentradoras.sec_proceso, conCuentasConcentradoras.sec, ISNULL(conCuentasConcentradoras.FechaAlta, '') AS FechaAlta, conCuentasConcentradorasCDE.idCodigoRastreo, conCuentasConcentradoras.ClaveProveedor, adcProveedores.nombre , SUM(conCuentasConcentradoras.Monto) AS Monto, conCuentasConcentradoras.Usuario, conCuentasConcentradoras.CuentaCOG, cogdependencias.nombre
                FROM conCuentasConcentradoras 
                            INNER JOIN adcProveedores ON conCuentasConcentradoras.ClaveProveedor = adcProveedores.claveproveedor
                            INNER JOIN cogdependencias ON conCuentasConcentradoras.CuentaCOG = cogdependencias.idCatCOG
                            INNER JOIN conCuentasConcentradorasCDE ON conCuentasConcentradoras.sec_proceso = conCuentasConcentradorasCDE.sec_proceso
                                GROUP BY conCuentasConcentradoras.sec, conCuentasConcentradoras.sec_proceso, conCuentasConcentradoras.FechaAlta, conCuentasConcentradorasCDE.idCodigoRastreo, conCuentasConcentradoras.ClaveProveedor, adcProveedores.nombre , conCuentasConcentradoras.Usuario, conCuentasConcentradoras.CuentaCOG, cogdependencias.nombre
                                ORDER BY FechaAlta DESC
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradezco su ayuda.

---

@nachospiu esta es la salida de tu query:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y estos son los registros con sec_ proceso= 175 que contiene la tabla conCuentasConcentradoras
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

solo son dos

Comment: y necesitas la columna sec? y la columna fecha? si queres agrupar, para que servirian esas columnas? que valor deberian tener?

Comment: Hola,  gbianchi gracias por responder, entiendo lo que dices, pero si se requieren esas columnas para poder presentar al usuario y desde el datagrid hacer otros procesos

Comment: Entonces, si esas columnas se requieren, que esperas sumar? cual valor de esas columnas es el deseable al hacer la suma? no queda nada claro lo que queres mostrar, esa columna no puede tener multiples valores, porque entonces, que estarias sumando en la columna suma? pone el resultado esperado, y te vas a dar cuenta que algo no encaja....

Comment: ok explico un poco el requerimiento, el sistema registra las facturas que se van a pagar y el pago se puede realizar hasta en 3 partes de las cuales el monto debe sumar el total de la factura, los pagos que suman una factura pueden tener diferente origen de ingreso, pero se registran en la misma tabla de ahi la columna sec_ proceso puede tener números repetidos, la columna sec es la que los diferencia ya que solo es un secuencial, en mi primer  data grid requiero presentar al usuario las facturas registradas a pagar con la fecha que se ingresó, el secuencial,  el monto total, y demás datos

Comment: en un segundo datat grid (detalles) es donde se deben mostrar las partes en que se dividió el pago de la factura y el origen del presupuesto, etc

Comment: aja.. entonces? no entiendo donde encaja este query con tu explicacion....

Comment: ok entiendo, posiblemente estés pensando debe haber una tabla de facturas para hacer un simple select con los datos que necesitas, bueno si existiera tal cosa créeme no tendría necesidad de haber empezado este post, a alguien se le hizo fácil leer las facturas directamente de los archivos xml, y solo guardar las partes en que se dividió para pagarse

Comment: Yo solo leo lo que vos escribis, no estoy pensando en nada. Lo que si pienso, es que tu query no tiene logica en algun punto. Cual es la salida que queres? si la mostras, te vas a dar cuenta que son dos querys distintos los que me nombras... tal vez sea por ahi el problema?

Answer (score 0):

No se si entendí bien lo que necesitas, si tu quieres que en el reporte anterior aparezca el monto total por sec_proceso (en lugar del monto parcial, como aparece actualmente) pero manteniendo las columnas sec y FechaAlta, lo que puedes hacer es un `INNER JOIN` con una subquery que sume el monto agrupando por sec_proceso.

De esta manera en el resultado aparecerán las columnas sec y FechaAlta junto al monto total de dicho sec_proceso (en lugar del monto parcial para ese sec, o podríás mostrar tanto el monto parcial como el total).

Para las filas en las que sec_proceso sea el mismo coincidirá el monto total (conCuentasConcentradorasTotal.Monto), ya que es el monto total de dicho sec_proceso (la suma de los montos parciales).

No conozco tu modelo de datos así que quizas mi query necesite algún retoque.

```
SELECT conCuentasConcentradoras.sec_proceso, 
    conCuentasConcentradoras.sec, 
    ISNULL(conCuentasConcentradoras.FechaAlta, '') AS FechaAlta, 
    conCuentasConcentradorasCDE.idCodigoRastreo, 
    conCuentasConcentradoras.ClaveProveedor, 
    adcProveedores.nombre , 
    conCuentasConcentradorasTotal.Monto, 
    conCuentasConcentradoras.Usuario, 
    conCuentasConcentradoras.CuentaCOG,
    cogdependencias.nombre

FROM conCuentasConcentradoras 
INNER JOIN adcProveedores ON conCuentasConcentradoras.ClaveProveedor = adcProveedores.claveproveedor
INNER JOIN cogdependencias ON conCuentasConcentradoras.CuentaCOG = cogdependencias.idCatCOG
INNER JOIN conCuentasConcentradorasCDE ON conCuentasConcentradoras.sec_proceso = conCuentasConcentradorasCDE.sec_proceso
INNER JOIN (SELECT sec_proceso, SUM(Monto) AS Monto FROM conCuentasConcentradoras GROUP BY sec_proceso) AS conCuentasConcentradorasTotal ON conCuentasConcentradoras.sec_proceso = conCuentasConcentradorasTotal.sec_proceso

ORDER BY FechaAlta DESC;
```

Comment: Hola, nachospiu gracias por responder ya probé tu sugerencia, solo que me da más duplicados, ahora me arroja 6 registros con sec_proceso 175, la suma la hace correcto pero duplica varias veces los registros

Comment: @ErikcSanchezFlores creo que el problema se debe a que tienes 2 filas en la tabla `cogdependencias` con `idCatCOG = 3.1.1.01` (lo que duplica el registro con esa dependencia) y 2 filas en la tabla `conCuentasConcentradorasCDE` con `sec_proceso = 175` lo que duplica los 2 registros. Por lo tanto en el resultado verás 6 registros con `sec_proceso = 175`. Si esta bien que así sea, deberás modificar tu query original para que no los duplique.